# Highlighting Palindromes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to highlight all 6 letter palindromes displayed on a webpage. I found this javascript function [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FutureWebDev/HfS7e/) and believe i’ve adapted it accordingly.

```
function highlight() {
    var query = new RegExp("([ATCG])([ATCG])([ATCG])(\\3)(\\2)(\\1)", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;
}
```

When I run the function (by clicking a link) none of the text highlights. It works if just put a regular string in there so I thought it was the regular expression giving the problem but tested it online and found it works. [RegEx Test](https://regex101.com/r/qN2bD0/1)

Comment: "and believe i’ve adapted it accordingly" --- programming is not about either adapting or belief :-S Remove it entirely and reimplement from the scratch. Than ask if in stuck.

Answer (score 2):

A more *intuivite* breakdown, which includes upper and lower case matches:

```
function highlightPal() {
    var e = document.getElementById("searchtext");
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML
                 .replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "")
                 .replace(
                     new RegExp("([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z])(\\3)(\\2)(\\1)","gim"),
                     "<span>$&</span>"
                 );
}
```

#### Try it below ▾

```js
function highlightPal() {
    var e = document.getElementById("searchtext");
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML
                 .replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "")
                 .replace(
                     new RegExp("([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z])(\\3)(\\2)(\\1)","gim"),
                     "<span>$&</span>"
                 );
}
highlightPal();
```

```css
span{background:#FF9;color:#555;}body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding:0 1em;}p{margin:.8em 0;}
```

```html
<div id="searchtext"><p>JavaScript is the programming language of the Web. The overwhelming CGTTGCAATTAAGGCCGG browsers—on desktops, game consoles, tablets, and smart phones—include JavaScript pallap  interpreters, making its first-class functions hoooooooooh from Scheme, terms, to use this book and learn JavaScript.</p><p>The name oooooooooooooooo"JavaScript" is actually rerrer somewhat misleading. <span>Except</span> for a scripting-language tuttut roots to become a robust and efficient general-purpose language.</p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because of the parentheses in your RegEx constructor definition that create another capturing group.

```
var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
```

The regex I'd use is `([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])\3\2\1`, and it should be hard-coded. Here is the function:

```
function highlightSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById("query").value;
     var query = new RegExp("(?:\\b([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])\\3\\2\\1\\b)", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$&</span>");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it using `match` and `replace`:

```js
function highlight() {
  var regex = /([ATCG])([ATCG])([ATCG])(\3)(\2)(\1)/gim;
  var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
  var enew = e.match(regex);
  for (var i = 0; i < enew.length; i++) {
    e = e.replace(enew[i], '<span>' + enew[i] + '</span>');
  }
  document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = e;
}

highlight();
```

```css
#searchtext span:nth-child(n) {
  color: red;
}
#searchtext span:nth-child(2n) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchtext">ATTTTAACTGTGATTAGGRAAGCCGAYAYCGTTGCAATTAAGGCCGG</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd use `match()` and `replace(...)` over just `replace(/.../g)`?

Comment: Not really - but it helps if ever you want to deal with one or some matches differently to others.